# Python Regexp Sub Function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use the sub function in python but cannot get it to work. So far I have

```
content = '**hello**'
content = re.sub('**(.*)**', '<i>(.*)</i>', content)
```

I am trying to make the

```
**hello**
```

be replaced with

```
<i>hello</i>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your expected output for  something like `**foo**bar**`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `*` character, and use the replacement function:

```
content = '**hello**'
content = re.sub('\*\*(.*)\*\*', lambda p : '<i>%s</i>' % p.group(1), content)
```

As an alternative, you can use named groups.

```
content = re.sub('\*\*(?P<name>.*)\*\*', '<i>\g<name></i>', '**hello**')
```

Or as a better alternative, numbered groups.

```
content = re.sub('\*\*(.*)\*\*', '<i>\\1</i>', '**hello**')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it replaces with <i>(.*)</i> instead of <i>hello</i>

Comment: this doesn't gives the required answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, but say I had ***hello*** and I only wanted to match it if it was **hello** how would I achieve that?

Comment: Instead of a replacement function, you could just use `r'<i>\1</i>'`